# How do I uninstall a powershell module from my computer?

Tags: windows, powershell

I installed a Powershell module (posh-git) using PS-Get but I am finding that it is quite slow. I want to uninstall it but using `Remove-Module posh-git` only uninstalls it from my current session but I would like to make this permanent.

Comment: This looks like a [su] question, not for here, to me

Comment: @JanDvorak There are over 80,000 questions on SO for `powershell` - I looked before posting. Please move my question to Super User (or ask me to) which wouldn't affect my rep for asking an honest and relevant question. There are now 98 stackexchange sites and powershell could fall into more than one bucket

Comment: There are over 1,000,000 questions on SO about computers. That doesn't mean every question about computers is valid here.

Comment: Hi @JanDvorak ok. I vote to move it to Super User

Comment: This is still a question directly related to programming tools. Many of those are on topic here. It's not always about code directly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an open issue for PS-GET: https://github.com/psget/psget/issues/164:

> This should be a feature.
>   Nowadays, you have to delete it manually from `C:\Users\[yourUser]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\modules` directory.

Comment: finally! after all this time

Comment: In my case was `C:\Users\[yourUser]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Comment: for Windows 11 with OneDrive - `C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`